# Powershell Get-EventLog how to strip out Caller Computer Name into a variable

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

I want to grab the value listed under "Caller Computer Name" and put it in a variable so that I can use it to get the IP address of the computer in another command.

This is the code I am using to pull the data:

```
$event= Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC -InstanceId 4740 -Newest 1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the property MachineName directly like this:

```
$machine_name= (Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC -InstanceId 4674 -Newest 1).MachineName
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect after changing the InstanceId to 4740

Comment: @ToddWelch: Yes, some people can't accept the way an issue can be handled. They will spend hours and if they don't come up with something, then they will burst on down-voting proper ans. :P

Comment: well I can only imagine how much there life must suck to feel the need to do something like that.

Comment: Thats the beauty of life @Todd . :)